# Python subprocess.call is not running the same as with python shell

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to merge 2 python scripts(***before.py and after.py***) to one as I need to set a cron job for the python script to run both scripts in one execution.

The 2 scripts are connected wherein the file that is processed by ***after.py*** (tmp1.txt) is being generated by ***before.py***.

Original order of script is

```
python3 before.py someCsv.csv > tmp1.txt
python3 after.py tmp1.txt >tmp2.txt
```

in before.py, I added this
`subprocess.call(' python3 after.py tmp1.txt > tmp2.txt', shell=True)`

Which I believe will allow to execute a run a shell command inside python.

[image]

If I run the script directly (after.py), it returns 44,623 records. 
But if i run after.py within before.py via subprocess.call(), it returns only 44,619 records.

I am using the same file in both scripts ,that is tmp1.txt.

I tried subprocess.call(), subprocess.run(), and os.system(). It seems that I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: Has the first script finished writing to the file? Why do you not just call a method from the after script directly in the before script?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This is the code for 'before.py' (https://imgur.com/I7opL3Q), which should run as expected. What I don't understand is that the `python3 after.py tmp1.txt > tmp2.txt` should give the same result. It should be the same as calling a method after the 'before.py' script right?

Comment: `before.py` prints its output, it doesn't write to a file, you're almost certainly calling after on the previous run's data. What does `after.py` do? You may be able to combine them into a single script

Comment: Ah, I'm slowly getting it now. For the after.py, I just made it like this (https://imgur.com/a8Jq4NA) for the sake of merging it. I just want to be able to display same records when i dump the no of records of the txt file. When I check the create tmp1.txt by before.py the recrods are 44,623 so its a little strange why it's returning 44,619. Why the 4 records are missing? :o

Answer (score 0):

instead of outputting the result to a new file via ">" in python shell, I just created a new file within before.py which guarantees that before after.py will run, tmp1.txt is 100% completed. Which allows me to get the full 44,623 records.

This is the end of before.py. Instead of directly outputting to a file within the python shell, I just created the file within the script itself.
[image]